# Add view to Fragment programmatically Android

Tags: java, android, fragment

In my fragment1 I add view like this:

`CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)new CheckBox(getActivity());
linearLayout.addView(chb);`

When I load fragment2 to activity's container and then return back to fragment1, there is no added view.

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "return back to fragment1"?  If you mean loading the fragment again (or replacing one with fragment1) then the added view will not be there.  Since you added it programatically, there's nothing to persist it.

Comment: @Martin I add fragment1 to back stack and replace fragment1 by fragment2 then I click Back. Is it possible to add view programmatically to fragment and persist SOMEHOW? Or may be I should use Activity, not Fragment?

Comment: Not any kind of existing method that I know of.  However, you might be able to architect some code that uses sharedPreferences to set which fragment is loaded and then, in your java code, examine sharedPreferences for which fragment to load where.  I did something similar with the ordering of items in a listview, but see no reason why it wouldn't work here

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Can you confirm there is no way to restore programmatically added views when you get back from fragment 2 to fragment 1 ?